# Como puedo usar diferentes hilos con un timer en java

Tags: java, hilos

Tengo un programa en java que revisa una base de datos cada segundo, si encuentra un nuevo registro realiza cierto proceso, pero si en el tiempo que está procesando ese registro entra otro me gustaría que la aplicación abriera un nuevo hilo e iniciara el proceso para ese registro en paralelo del otro. ¿Es posible esto?

Este es el código que tengo actualmente

```
package middlewareivr;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class MiddlewareIVR {

  public static void main(String[] args){
      Proceso p = new Proceso();
  
       final Runnable tarea = new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            try {
                p.ejecutaProceso();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MiddlewareIVR.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
          } 
       };
       ScheduledExecutorService timer = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
       timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(tarea, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }
}
```

En este código lo que hago es que cada segundo se ejecute la tarea Runnable que a su vez correrá el proceso de revisar si hay un nuevo registro en la base de datos y realizar sus respectivas tareas, sino  esperará la siguiente ejecución. Pero no he logrado que si entra otro registro mientras se está procesando uno se abra un nuevo hilo para procesar ese nuevo registro. he intentado cambiar el *newSingleThreadScheduledExcecutor* por *newScheduledThreadPool(i)* pero el proceso se realiza de la misma manera, hasta que termina de procesar un registro continua con el siguiente.
¿Podrían orientarme sobre si es posible hacer lo que deseo y cómo podría hacerlo?